# Proving that the bias of the derivative of Parzen-Rosenblatt (kernel density) estimator is of order $O(h^2) $ and $O(h)$ when $h$ approaches $0$

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, taylor-expansion, density-function, nonparametric-statistics

I'm trying to calculate the bias of this estimator of $f$ a $C^4$ mesurable function:

$$\hat{f'}_{h,n} = \cfrac{1}{nh^2}\sum_{j=1}^n K'\left(\cfrac{x-X_j}{h}\right) =\cfrac{1}{h^2}K'\left(\cfrac{x-X_1}{h}\right)$$

with $K$ being the standard normal distribution and $K'$ its derivative.

The formula for the bias is this :

$$B\left(\hat{f'}_{h,n}\right)= E\left(\hat{f'}_{h,n}(x)\right) - f'(x)$$

**My goal is to prove that this bias is of order $O(h^2)$ and $O(h)$ when $h$ approaches $0$.**

Here is my attempt :

$$E\left(\hat{f'}_{h,n}(x)\right) = \int\cfrac{1}{h^2}K'\left(\cfrac{u-x}{h}\right)f'(u)$$

Let $u = x +hv$ so we get :
$$ E\left(\hat{f'}_{h,n}(x)\right) = \cfrac{1}{h}\int f'(hv+x) K'(v)dv $$

Now I'm thinking about using taylor's expansion for f when $ h $ approaches $0$:

$$f'(hv+x) = f^{(2)}hv +\cfrac{(hv)^2}{2} f^{3}(x)+\cfrac{(hv)^3}{3!}f^{4}(x)+ o(h^3)$$

but seeing this calculation, I don't know whether it will get me to prove that the order is indeed $O(h^2)$ and $O(h)$.

**How should I proceed?**